# How to set background image Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to put a simple image in background project Xamarin Android... in my project i can see the image,but whem i build, dont show in my App..
[image: here]
as you can see,my background image call hue.jpg and this is my XML file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:background="@drawable/hue" />
```

So... what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the resolution of the image a lot higher than the screen used? If so try scaling down the resolution and try again..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the resolution of the image a lot higher than the screen used? If so try scaling down the resolution and try again.

Comment: It worked for me, just add the line android:background="@drawable/my_background"  to the LinearLayout header and storing the image my_background.png in the /Resources/drawable folder of the solution. I'm using a 540x960px image, it's the half of 1920x1080, and looks pretty well on my emulator and device even using different display resolutions.