# Wide image not displaying on tablet

Tags: c#, android, image, bitmap, xamarin

I use canvas and bitmap for create image.
I add my image in ScrollView (600x400).

```
int width = 2048;
int height = 600;

ImageView myImage = new ImageView(context);
Bitmap bitmapChart = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
Canvas canvasChart = new Canvas(bitmapChart);

var paint = new Paint();
paint.Color = Color.Red;
paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
canvasChart.DrawRect(rect, paint);

myImage.SetImageBitmap(bitmapChart);
HorizontalScrollView scrollView1 = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
scrollView1.LayoutParameters.Height = 400;
scrollView1.LayoutParameters.Width = 600;
scrollView1.AddView(myImage);
this.AddView(scrollView1);
```

But if width of my image will be 2049 or more, this image will not displaying on tablet (on emulator it works normally).

Why I can't see my image?

Comment: Please provide some code how you disaply the image

Comment: have a look at this and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597833/how-to-set-background-image-xamarin-android/29600679#29600679

Comment: Can I display wide image? I added my Image in ScrollView